In package `ggmulti` , how to add value label to the plot
In ggmulti , how to add value label to the plot ?
When I using geom_text  show ....It will be omitted
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmulti)
nba <- NBAstats2021 %>%
  mutate(
    dPTS = PTS - OPTS,
    dREB = REB - OREB,
    dAST = AST - OAST,
    dTO = TO - OTO
  )


ggplot(nba %>% head(2),
       mapping = aes(
         dREB = dREB,
         dAST = dAST,
         dTO = dTO,
         colour = Team
         
       )) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_text(aes(label= dREB)) +
  geom_text(aes(label= dAST)) +
  geom_text(aes(label= dTO)) +
  coord_serialaxes(axes.layout = "radial") 


I get this Warning message:
The layer GeomText is not implemented in serialaxes coordinate yet. It will be omitted.
